# pandas.read_fwf ignores dtypes provided

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing a dataframe from a text file
I'd like to specify the data type of the columns, but pandas seems to ignore the `dtype` input.

A working example:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

string = 'USAF   WBAN  STATION NAME                  CTRY ST CALL  LAT     LON      ELEV(M) BEGIN    END\n007026 99999 WXPOD 7026                    AF            +00.000 +000.000 +7026.0 20120713 20170822\n007070 99999 WXPOD 7070                    AF            +00.000 +000.000 +7070.0 20140923 20150926'

f = StringIO(string)

df = pd.read_fwf(f,
                 colspecs = [(0,6),
                             (7,12),
                             (13,41),
                             (43,45),
                             (48,50),
                             (51,55),
                             (57,64),
                             (65,73),
                             (74,81),
                             (82,90),
                             (91,101)],
                 dtypes = {'USAF'         : str,
                           'WBAN'         : str,
                           'STATION NAME' : str,
                           'CT'           : str,
                           'ST'           : str,
                           'CALL'         : str,
                           'LAT'          : float,
                           'LON'          : float,
                           'ELEV(M)'      : float,
                           'BEGIN'        : int,
                           'END'          : int,},
                 )
df.dtype
```

returns

```
USAF              int64
WBAN              int64
STATION NAME     object
CT               object
ST              float64
CALL            float64
LAT             float64
LON             float64
ELEV(M)         float64
BEGIN             int64
END               int64
dtype: object
```

Why does this happen? How can I force the first columns to be strings?

Comment: issues with dtype args in read_fwf [link to git](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7141) as below please use converters...good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are issues with dtype conversion with read_fwf.  This is Pandas guessing the type and applying.  Use `converters` here explicitly.  You have to do this during DataFrame creation as you will lose leading `0`s if you convert afterwards.

```
string = 'USAF   WBAN  STATION NAME                  CTRY ST CALL  LAT     LON      ELEV(M) BEGIN    END\n007026 99999 WXPOD 7026                    AF            +00.000 +000.000 +7026.0 20120713 20170822\n007070 99999 WXPOD 7070                    AF            +00.000 +000.000 +7070.0 20140923 20150926'

f = StringIO(string)
df = pd.read_fwf(f,
                 colspecs = [(0,6),
                             (7,12),
                             (13,41),
                             (43,45),
                             (48,50),
                             (51,55),
                             (57,64),
                             (65,73),
                             (74,81),
                             (82,90),
                             (91,101)],
                converters = {'USAF':lambda x : str(x),
                              'WBAN':lambda x : str(x),
                              'STATION NAME':lambda x : str(x),
                              'CT':lambda x : str(x),
                              'ST':lambda x : str(x),
                              'CALL':lambda x : str(x)}
                 )
>>> df.dtypes
USAF             object
WBAN             object
STATION NAME     object
CT               object
ST               object
CALL             object
LAT             float64
LON             float64
ELEV(M)         float64
BEGIN             int64
END               int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you. Just one curiosity: isn’t ‘lambda x: str(x)’ the same as ‘str’? Or more generally, isn’t ‘lambda x: fun(x)’ the same as ‘fun’?

Comment: @Amerio Converters requires a function.  You could specify a function(n) to return str(n) before the DF but this does it in one shot.  Upvote if helpful!!

Comment: @LucaAmerio — Yes, you are correct! Instead of `lambda x: str(x)`, you can instead simply just write `str` because in Python a type like `str` behaves like a function when called. (As is evident in the lambda itself, for example, where it behaves like a function.)